# How can I loop through a list in Excel VBA and concatenate unique and duplicate IDs from two columns?

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops, concatenation

I am trying to loop through a list of IDs in column A and return the (last or 5th character) of the ID string for unique/distinct ID’s in column B.

Next, I want to look at duplicated IDs (based on the first 4 characters) of the ID string and return the last (or 5th character) of the ID string in the cell adjacent to the first duplicate (please see below picture). The idea is to concatenate the parsed (last or 5th character) from each of the duplicate values and return them in the cell adjacent in column B (please see below picture).

[image: Example of final result I'm looking for]

I tried using the VBA example found [here](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/), but could not get it to work for my problem.

Comment: Do you need `VBA` solution or formula is okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, **only if the ID value is always 5 character** ....

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, c As Range, d As Range
Dim arr, fa As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rg: arr.Item(Left(cell.Value, 4)) = 1: Next

    For Each el In arr
    Set c = Columns(1).Find(el, lookat:=xlPart, after:=Cells(1, 1))
    fa = c.Address
    Set d = c.Offset(0, 1): d.Value = Right(c.Value, 1)
        Do
            Set c = Columns(1).Find(el, lookat:=xlPart, after:=c)
            If d.Find(Right(c.Value, 1), lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing _
            Then d.Value = d.Value & ", " & Right(c.Value, 1)
        Loop Until c.Address = fa
    Next

End Sub
```

The sub create range variable from A2 to whatever lastrow with data as rg.
Then it loop to each cell in rg to create a unique value which is the first four character from the left of the looped cell value as arr variable.

Then it loop to each element in arr.
Get the first found cell in column A which value is the looped element as c variable, then set a range of c.offset(0,1) as d variable and fill the d with the last character of c value.

Then it loop to find the next element in column A, and check if the next found cell last character value not exist in d, it add this last character to d.

[image] ---> [image]

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked as well. Both are brilliant! Much thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

### Join Trailing Characters

[image]

```vb
Sub JoinUniqueTrailingChars()
    
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const CHAR_COUNT As Long = 1
    Const CHAR_DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Set srg = ws.Range(.Cells, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim sData()
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim rDict As Object: Set rDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim cDict As Object: Set cDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    cDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long, sStr As String, dlStr As String, drStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sStr = CStr(sData(r, 1))
        If Len(sStr) >= CHAR_COUNT Then
            dlStr = Left(sStr, Len(sStr) - CHAR_COUNT)
            drStr = Right(sStr, CHAR_COUNT)
            If Not rDict.Exists(dlStr) Then
                rDict(dlStr) = r
                Set cDict(dlStr) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                cDict(dlStr).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                cDict(dlStr)(drStr) = Empty
            Else
                If Not cDict(dlStr).Exists(drStr) Then
                    cDict(dlStr)(drStr) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim rKey
    
    For Each rKey In rDict.Keys
        dData(rDict(rKey), 1) = Join(cDict(rKey).Keys, CHAR_DELIMITER)
    Next rKey
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Unique trailing characters joined.", vbInformation

End Sub
```