# How can I loop through a list in Excel VBA and concatenate unique and duplicate IDs & Qtys from two columns?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a link to my original post a few months back. [How can I loop through a list in Excel VBA and concatenate unique and duplicate IDs from two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285694/how-can-i-loop-through-a-list-in-excel-vba-and-concatenate-unique-and-duplicate)

I would like to know if the original VBA solution(s) provided (in the referenced link above) can be modified to also pull in/return the quantity values in column B of the below example? I'm not sure how to modify the code to pull in the qtys; especially, when the qtys are 2, 3 or 4 digit qtys etc. Please see updated picture/example below of the values I'm looking to return in column B.

I tried modifying the code myself, but due to my limited vba skills, I was unable to figure out how to adjust the code to account for situations where the qty > 1 digit. Please see updated picture/example below of the values I'm looking to return in column B.

Many thanks!

[image: Results example]

Here's a copy of the code I tried to modify (see below). However, I was not able to figure out how to modify it to account for qtys > 1 digit.

```vb
Sub test2()

Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, c As Range, d As Range
Dim arr, fa As String 

With Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each cell In rg: arr.Item(Left(cell.Value, 4)) = 1: Next 
    For Each el In arr
    Set c = Columns(1).Find(el, lookat:=xlPart, after:=Cells(1, 1))
    'Debug.Print c.Address
    fa = c.Address

    'Debug.Print "fa: " & fa
    Set d = c.Offset(0, 1): d.Value = Right(c.Value, 4)

        Do
            Set c = Columns(1).Find(el, lookat:=xlPart, after:=c)
            If d.Find(Right(c.Value, 3), lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing _
            Then d.Value = d.Value & ", " & Right(c.Value, 4)  
        Loop Until c.Address = fa 
    Next   
    Range("B1").Value = "RESULT"
   
End Sub
```

Comment: "I tried modifying the code myself" - if you did this then it's useful to show us what you tried, and explain what specific problem you had with it...

Comment: Please see code I tried to modify above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim dict As Object, rw As Range, v, k, suff
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    For Each rw In Range("A2:B9").Rows  'loop input rows
        v = rw.Cells(1).Value
        rw.Cells(2).ClearContents       'clear any existing output
        If Len(v) >= 4 Then             'long enough?
            k = Left(v, 4)
            'store each new key, the corresponding output cell, and an empty collection
            If Not dict.Exists(k) Then dict.Add k, Array(rw.Cells(2), New Collection)
            If Len(v) > 4 Then
                suff = Mid(v, 5, Len(v) - 4) 'value beyond the key
                On Error Resume Next
                dict(k)(1).Add suff, suff 'add to collection, enforcing uniqueness
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    
    'write the outputs for each unique 4-character stem
    For Each k In dict
        dict(k)(0).Value = JoinCollection(dict(k)(1), ",")
    Next k
End Sub

'Concatenate all items in collection with `sep`
Function JoinCollection(col, sep As String)
    Dim el, sp
    For Each el In col
        JoinCollection = JoinCollection & sp & el
        sp = sep
    Next el
End Function
```

Comment: This worked...thank you so much!!